# mongodb columns constraints in python like ruby mongoid

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoid

In the past, I have used `mongoid` for ruby 
that way, I could have specify mongodb constraints in the app level

```
class UserData < BaseMongoid

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :user_id,         type: Integer
  field :popups_seen,      type: Hash,      default: {seen_dqp: false}
  field :preferences,     type: Hash,      default: {}
```

I didn't find anything like that in python .
any takes?

Comment: thanks @chridam that looks exactly like what I need, post your comment as a question and i'll approve. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[Mongoengine](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/defining-documents.html#defining-a-document-s-schema)**, the Document-Object Mapper equivalent of mongoid for working with MongoDB from Python. As an example from the docs, to define a schema for a document, create a class that inherits from Document. Fields are specified by adding field objects as class attributes to the document class:

```
from mongoengine import *
import datetime

class Page(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```